# VBA Range Empty Sub, how to send user back to fill range

Tags: vba

```
Sub Emptys()

Dim r As Range
Dim totalCells As Integer

'My range To check'
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:CS71")

'Check for filled cells'
totalCells = r.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r)

If totalCells = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Range is empty, go back and enter"

End If

End Sub
```

How can I send a user back to sheet and fill range from this sub? It's on a "print data" and the next call after this would be a print macro. The command button is calling to check for empty, msgbox pops up and then debugs on printer macro.

Thank you

Comment: Aren't they already on the sheet?  You use `ActiveSheet` in your code.

Comment: You could use `Application.Goto ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), Scroll:=True` which sends them to the range you set putting cell B3 in their top left corner. Otherwise you could just `Select` or `Activate` a cell which will send them to it as well but not as good as goto in my opinion.

Comment: @simon, I put Application.Goto under MsgBox line but it still pushes through to print macro

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Emptys(r As Range)
Dim totalCells As Integer, r2 As Range
totalCells = r.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r)
If totalCells = 0 Then
    On Error GoTo err
    Set r2 = Application.InputBox("Please Enter valid range or range with data", , , , , , , 8)
    Emptys r2
 End If
err:
    If err.Number = 424 Then Exit Sub
 End Sub
'Calling sub.
Sub calling()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Range("Your range")
Emptys rng
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't get an error, I coudln't figure out how to place it in the code line

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: Then comment out On Error GoTO.. line and err: and below line and check what's the error.

Comment: Here's the drive link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqwMTlWln5QfyCn9wHHoox3hBsE9?e=Dc6fnu       code is on BIBS & Topics sheet

Comment: Hey...Replace your Module 1 with my code..Right now input box will upon until it does not contain some data...But you have error on printout section..Edit that according to your need.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17PiKR-tIA2oySU2Ipx6c07jiYf3ElC9l/view?usp=sharing